# Create Custom Package in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

I want to create a custom label package but I don't really know how to do it.

I'm doing this:

File->New->Package

And then Add->New Component

I choose the ancester type, etc. finally click on Create New Component.

I got the following unit code.

```
unit MyLabel1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, LResources, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyLabel1 = class(TLabel)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Standard',[TMyLabel1]);
end;

end.
```

My Question is:

1. How can I set the font style like Color and Name in the code above?

When I select the custom label from the stardard pallet into a Form I want to have these properties already set.

I appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Set them in `constructor`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **TEnhancedPanel** example in [**wiki**](http://wiki.freepascal.org/How_to_Write_a_Lazarus_Component).